# How to rebuild Vue via shell_exec()

Tags: php, vue.js, nginx, npm

I have a Vue application that receives updates via webhook.php - there is a little php script that updates internal configs.
At the end of this webhook.php file I have

`echo shell_exec('sudo ../deploy.sh');`

deploy.sh contains pretty much one line (I want to expand it a little bit later):

`sudo npm run build`

PHP script is doing it's work - configs are getting updated, but the build is not happening.

shell_exec() outputs nothing meaning that there is some error.

var/log/nginx/ does't show any errors.

My guess it's some problem with permissions - when I run `shell_exec('sudo ../deploy.sh')` from terminal, it works just like it should. But not from the webhook.php.

Answer (score 0):

first try to use full path and redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, then background it.

`shell_exec('sudo /var/www/html/deploy.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`